# Проблема с WInForms

Tags: c#

Есть изначальная форма с датагридом, на ней есть кнопка, которая создает вторую форму, в которой есть текстовые данные, откуда пойдут данные в датагрид из формы 1. На 2ой форме есть кнопка "Подтвердить", которая передает данные в датагрид и закрывает 2ую форму, как это реализовать? 
Думал что-то вроде такого:

```
Confirm.Click += new EventHandler(Confirm_Click);
```

Естественно создать до этого функцию для кнопки, но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант.

Сделать доступными из вне(свойство `Modifers` равно `Public` или `Internal`) те элементы управления, из которых будут считываться данные. Кнопке на второй форме задать `DialogResult` (например `Ok`) и проверять `DialogResult` уже самой второй формы при её закрытии.

Если её `DialogResult` равен нужному значению (например, тому же `Ok`), вносить считывать данные и вносить их в грид.